# What is this 9609SB?

Tags: power-supply, identification

This IC is from a power supply for an LED domestic light

[image: LED supply]

[image: PCB]

This appears to be a 7 legged IC, at least it doesn’t seem to have had the 7th leg snipped.

[image: 9609 IC]

The markings seem to be

```
9609SB
G8EMOS
```

I have had a google and I don’t think that it is an AD9609 ADC nor a [9609 MOSFET](https://www.mouser.com/Semiconductors/Discrete-Semiconductors/Transistors/MOSFET/Datasheets/_/N-ax1sf?keyword=9609).

Comment: Perhaps some sort of LED driver. Just a wild guess: https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/1112315/SISemiconductors/SIC9753/1. Warning: me friendly hobbyist. No guarantee no nothing won't melt down or blow up. Good luck and cheers.

Comment: Would you care to post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to the datasheet, [JD9609](http://www.jdsemi.cn/static/upload/file/20230205/1675562584153730.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same IC and found the [WS9002](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/1351316/Winsemi/WS9002/1). I've checked the pin out and it is correct.

[image: WS9002 application circuit]

Please, reply if you find any replacement or a easy way of dimming it.

Comment: See [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/705054/64015).

Answer (score 1):

Check this out pin out. Looks similar to the part reference in the question.

[image: MBI6655 Pinout]

This application circuit has similar components per the question. Example Pin 4 SW is connected to diode.

[image: MBI6655 application circuit]

Here is link to the [datasheet](https://www.neumueller.com/datenblatt/macroblock/MBI6655%20Datenblatt%20-%20Datasheet.pdf).

Additionally [MB10](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/115/MB10S-1112788.pdf) looks like a bridge rectifier. These should help identify the components.

Comment: Similar, but not quite, as pin 8 of the IC in my PCB is used (it's connected to two resistors). I will add a schematic of the PCB, it will probably help.